# How to set programatically the Id, Name and Class atribute of a @Html.EditFor or @Html.TextBoxFor - MVC 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to generate a unique label and and input text box for a partial view that is being used to render a list of user input rows.

By unique I mean that each input text box should have its unique html "id" and "name" so that when is submitted each input can be identified

In the **View** I have

```
@model UserDataModel

@{
    var inpName = "benefName" + @Model.Row;
    var inpAge = "benefAge" + @Model.Row;
}
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, new { @class="labelhalf"})
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name, new { id = @inpName, htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control animated" } })
```

When the view is being render this is what I am seeing

```
<label class="labelhalf" for="Name">Nombre (Opcional)</label>
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">
```

As you can see the "name" and "id" attributes of the text input is "Name" and "Name" and is not using the value of the @inpName variable ("benefName1" for example)

Also I am trying to assign some CSS classes to that same input using "htmlAttributes"

I had previously tried this with this approach

```
<label form="FormStep_01" for=@inpName class="labelhalf">Nombre (Opcional)</label>
<input form="FormStep_01" id=@inpName class="form-control animated" pattern="^[_A-z0-9]{1,}$" type="text" placeholder="" required="">
```

...but the content of the input fields with this approach are not being submited and that is the reason I am trying to use the @Html.EditorFor

**UPDATE**
I am now using the TextBoxFor which takes the "id" and the "class" fine but not the "name" which is used in the submit

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "labelhalf" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @id = @inpName, name = @inpName, @class = "form-control animated" })
```

Please let me know how to achieve this in MVC4

Comment: You cannot add `HmlAttributes` using `EditorFor()` in MVC-4. You need at least `MVC-5.1` (refer [mvc 5.1 whats new](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mvc%205.1%20whats%20new). But more importantly you should **never** try to override the `name` (or `value`) attributes set by the HtmlHelper (its the surest way to ensure your app fails) and the MVC built in safe guards to prevent you changing the `name` attribute. There is a workaround (but I wont tell you that) but you may as well just create the inputs manually.

Comment: You appear to have the classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). My best guess is you want to dynamically generate inputs for items in a collection property of a model, in which case I suggest you study the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Comment: @StephenMuecke when I created the inputs manually they were not being used in the submit (as I mentioned in my question)

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your last comment at all (and there is nothing in you question about manually creating them.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes there is look for text "I had previously tried this with this approach" and read on.

Comment: But you did not give the input a `name` attribute (so of course its not posted).` And why are you wanting to give them `id` attributes - what javascript are you using? Hopefully you have been through all 3 links I gave you previously.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i did got through the links and at the moment I did not realize that the name was not being used. Been working many hours in a row which produces this kind of dumb mistakes. Any how if you post that as an answer I could accept it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1 (Using `EditorFor()`)

You cannot add html attributes using `EditorFor()` in MVC-4. This feature was not introduced until MVC-5.1, and then the correct usage is

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeProperty, new { htmlAttributes = new { someAttribute = "someValue" }, })
```

Issue 2 (Using `TextBoxFor()`)

You cannot change the value of the  `name` attribute using `new { name = "someValue" }`. The MVC team built in a safe guard to prevent this because the whole purpose of using the `HtmlHelper` methods to generate form controls is to bind to your model properties, and doing this would cause binding to fail. While there is a workaround, if you do discover it, don't do it! As a side note - the following line of the `private static MvcHtmlString InputHelper()` method in the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs)

```
tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", fullName, true);
```

is what prevents you overriding it.

Issue 3 (Manual html)

You not giving the inputs a `name` attribute. A form posts back a name/value pair based on the `name` and `value` attributes of successful controls, so if there is no `name` attribute, nothing will be sent to the controller.

Side note: If your manually generating html, there is no real need to add an `id` attribute unless your referring to that element in javascript or css.

Its unclear why your trying to create a input for something that does not appear to relate to your model, but if your trying to dynamically generate items for adding items to a collection property in your model, refer the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options which will allow you to bind to your model.